# Create multiple columns using dynamic naming (dplyr approach)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose I have a vector of strings contains job vacancy requirements `df`. I also have a vector of strings contains programming language names `prog_langs`. I am looking for an **ellegent dplyr way**, how can I create within `mutate` method multiple columns for each programming language of vector `prog_langs` with certain column names `.name = "ProgLang_{prog_langs}" to test whether string of` df``` conitans particular progrmaming languge (TRUE if contains, FALSE otherwise).

```
# custom FUN
is_contains = function(txt, cond) if(grepl(cond, txt)) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE)

# Vector of programming languages
prog_langs = c("python", "java", "sql", "html")

# Vector of strings contains job vacancies requirements
df = data.frame("string" = c("exposure to scripting or programming languages (e.g python, c+, or powershell).", "scripting skills (e.g. java, javascript, beanshell, etc.)",
                             "basic understanding of sql", "html and css knowledge is a must."))


# example of code
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = vars(prog_langs), .fns = function(x) is_contains(txt = string, cond = x), .names = 'ProgLang_{.col}'))
```

**Desired output**:

New `df` with **N** new columns (where N is the length of prog_langs, i.e. number of programming languages), each of columns must contain TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses `tidyr::crossing` to obtain the cartesian product between `string` and `prog_langs`, then looks for matches using `grepl` and finally widens the `data.frame` using `tidyr::pivot_wider`

```r
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df |>
    crossing(ProgLang = prog_langs) |>
    mutate(contains = map2_lgl(ProgLang, string,  ~grepl(.x, .y))) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = ProgLang,
                values_from = contains,
                names_prefix = "ProgLang_")


##> + # A tibble: 4 × 5
##>   string                ProgLang_html ProgLang_java ProgLang_python ProgLang_sql
##>   <chr>                 <lgl>         <lgl>         <lgl>           <lgl>       
##> 1 basic understanding … FALSE         FALSE         FALSE           TRUE        
##> 2 exposure to scriptin… FALSE         FALSE         TRUE            FALSE       
##> 3 html and css knowled… TRUE          FALSE         FALSE           FALSE       
##> 4 scripting skills (e.… FALSE         TRUE          FALSE           FALSE
```

Edit as requested in the comment

```r
# Vector of programming languages
prog_langs <- c("python", "java", "sql", "html")
certificate <- c("oscp", "cissp", "ceh")

data.frame(Type = "ProgLang", pattern = prog_langs) |>
    rbind(data.frame(Type = "Certificate", pattern = certificate)) |>
    crossing(df) |>
    mutate(Contains = map2_lgl(pattern, string, grepl)) |>
    mutate(Thing = paste(Type, pattern, sep = "_"),
           .keep = "unused") |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = Thing, values_from = Contains)
    
##>  + # A tibble: 4 × 8
##>   string         Certificate_ceh Certificate_cis… Certificate_oscp ProgLang_html
##>   <chr>          <lgl>           <lgl>            <lgl>            <lgl>        
##> 1 basic underst… FALSE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE        
##> 2 exposure to s… FALSE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE        
##> 3 html and css … FALSE           FALSE            FALSE            TRUE         
##> 4 scripting ski… FALSE           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE        
##> # … with 3 more variables: ProgLang_java <lgl>, ProgLang_python <lgl>,
##> #   ProgLang_sql <lgl>
```

Comment: Looks amazing, but could you please rewrite your code for two or more groups of skills? i.e. programming languages and certificates for instance?

Comment: I think I need an example. Do you mean `df$certificate`?

Comment: wait there is an error!

Comment: should be fixed now!

Comment: I am sorry, but my request was misleading, I have another one vector of strings with certificates ```certificate = c("oscp", "cissp", "ceh")```, and I want to check whether job requirements contain it,  i.e. create second group of columns "certificates _{.col}"

Comment: OK, thank you, now it works properly, I really grateful your help

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr::map`, `purrr::transpose` and `tidyr::unnest_wider` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

prog_langs <- c("python", "java", "sql", "html")
names(prog_langs) <- prog_langs

df %>%
  mutate(ProgLang = transpose(map(prog_langs, ~ grepl(.x, string)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(ProgLang)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   string                                                python java  sql   html 
#>   <chr>                                                 <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 exposure to scripting or programming languages (e.g … TRUE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 2 scripting skills (e.g. java, javascript, beanshell, … FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 3 basic understanding of sql                            FALSE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 4 html and css knowledge is a must.                     FALSE  FALSE FALSE TRUE
```